# ImportError: No module named checks

Tags: python, ubuntu

so I'm following this tutorial :

https://github.com/SEL-Columbia/formhub/blob/master/docs/install/README.md

and insert this command :
 `python manage.py validate`

I receive this error :

> "ImportError: No module named checks "

i tried to download the django module , but i don't know if is installed.

someone could help me ? have  a way to see a log ? i think that is problem with Django module.